# jsPDF not working on button click

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

Hi I was trying to import script path for jsPDF and writing function on button click ,save html page to pdf. But its not working. Below is the code-

```html
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <script src="Scripts/jspdf.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){ 
      var doc = new jsPDF();
      var specialElementHandlers = {
       '#editor': function(element, renderer){
     return true;
       }
      };

      $('#cmd').click(function () {
        doc.fromHTML($('#content').get(0), 15, 15, {
     'width': 170, 
     'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        });
              doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
        });
      });
   </script>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
   <div id="content">
     <h3>Hello, this is a H3 tag</h3>

      <p>a pararaph</p>
   </div>
   <div id="editor"></div>
          <button href="#" id="cmd">generate PDF</button>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

But when I run the html and click on button, nothing happens. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can not call an element directly in the 'fromHTML' function.

Try:

```
var content = $('#content').get(0).html();
doc.fromHTML(content, 15, 1...{});
```